# I can't log in to admin site in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I am currently using a custom user model in django. After creating the user model and Migrating to db, we created the superuser account and ran the server. But after accessing the admin page, I entered my information correctly, but I couldn't log in. Can I know the cause? Here is my code

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, profile, nickname, password):
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            nickname=nickname,
            profile=profile,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, nickname, profile):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            nickname=nickname,
            profile=profile,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    profile = models.ImageField(default='default_image.jpeg')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'),default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nickname', 'profile']
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line **user.staff = True** should be **user.is_staff = True**

I think you will also need to add **user.is_superuser = True** just below that.